# How Parameterize Truncating a table in Azure SQL DB within an Azure Data Factory Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I following an SO question on how to truncate a table in Azure SQL DB with ADF
[how to replace data in azure sql database using azure data factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456500/how-to-replace-data-in-azure-sql-database-using-azure-data-factory)

I am trying to emulate the sample in the question using my Copy Activity as follows:

My Source details are as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the above configuration I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot find the object \"targettable\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot find the object \"targettable\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=4701,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=4701,State=1,Message=Cannot find the object \"targettable\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy From CRM to SQLDB",
    "details": []
}
```

However, if I were to hardcode the schema and table name as follows `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.mytablename` everything would work fine.

By way of an update, I just tried with the following parameters

```
TRUNCATE TableName@pipeline().parameters.TableName
```

And it failed.

Comment: did you try `TRUNCATE table @{pipeline().parameters.TableName}`?

Comment: Hi @RakeshGovindula, I haven't tried that. I will try that right now .. thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot find the object \"targettable\" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

This error occurred because of this query `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.targettable`.

- Here `targettable` is a SQL database parameter and we cannot access its value inside pipeline and also you have given it with query.
- It made the meaning of SQL query as to truncate the table named `targettable` which is not available in the database and that's why it gave you the above error.

To resolve it give the correct parameter in the query with **string interpolation** like below.

`TRUNCATE table @{pipeline().parameters.TableName}`

[image]

I have given the pipeline parameter as `sample1` which is my table name.

**Before Truncate:**

[image]

**After Truncate:**

[image]